# search numbers with egrep and regular expression

Tags: regex, linux, grep

Given a file `file1` with this text:

```
Anah, Julio, 5-3871 Ghin, Ermen, 4-4123 Jones, Thomas, 1-4122 Solor, R]ehard, 5-2522 Salazar, Hex, 8-2321 Jones, Tommy, 5-2911 Kar, Rt, 3-3633.
```

I want to use `egrep` to search all the numbers that start with 5 and end with 1.

I have tried:

```
grep '5' '1' file1
```

Comment: Please [edit] the post giving a [mcve]. Otherwise, we are losing time here

Comment: So what's the expected output of this?

Comment: do you want the whole line or only the numbers that satisfies these?

Comment: i want only the numbers :)

Comment: 5-3871 or 3871? Also, we would all benefit from you reading [ask].

Comment: it won't be possible only using grep till I know because grep returns the line if a pattern is matched in that line

Comment: @rock321987 you can say `grep -o 'pattern'` and just the pattern will be printed. -o stands for "only".

Comment: @fedorqui thanks..didn't knew about it

Comment: only 5-3871 the 5-2522 and the 5-2911

Comment: why 5-2522..it does not end with 1?

Comment: yes my mistake not 5-2522

Comment: then `egrep -o \\b5[0-9-]*1\\b inputfile` will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex will work

```
egrep -o \\b5[0-9-]*1\\b inputfile
```

*Regex Breakdown*

```
\\b # word boundary
5 #Number starts with 5
[0-9-]* #Any combination of 0-9 and -
1 # Ends with 1
\\b Word boundary
```

Comment: Or `egrep -o '\b5[0-9-]*1\b' inputfile`

Comment: @fedorqui yeah..that's another way

Comment: can you explain it? because i cant understand it?

Comment: @e.katyia I have added an explanation..see if its ok

Comment: @e.katyia you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) the answer if it helped

Comment: sorry for my delay i am new :) thanks for the answer